# How to add multiple publishers to get 4 camera images?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hai, I am writing a rospy code to publish images from 4 cameras. Currently, i trying it with my laptop camera.it works..but how to add multiple publishers for camera.
My code is...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

def webcam_pub():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('webcam/image_raw', Image, queue_size=1)
    rospy.init_node('webcam_pub', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(60) # 60hz

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    bridge = CvBridge()

    if not cam.isOpened():
         sys.stdout.write("Webcam is not available")
         return -1

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        ret, frame = cam.read()
    
        cv2.imshow("camera1",frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        msg = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame, encoding="bgr8")
        if ret:
             rospy.loginfo("Capturing image failed.")
        
        pub.publish(msg)
        rate.sleep()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        webcam_pub()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
      pass
```

I am using UBUNTU 16.04, KINETIC distro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288030/how-to-add-multiple-publishers-to-get-4-camera--images?/) by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2018-04-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-04-09**:
Cut and paste the text from the terminal window instead of using a screenshot.

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-04-09**:
updated..sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code works, you are only interpreting the return value wrong. "ret" is set if the capturing worked!

If you add a cv2.waitKey(1) after the imshow, the image is also shown. You should also only create publishers or subscribers after you created the nodehandle.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-04-09**:
thank you i add cv2.waitKey(1) camera is working..but it still showing [INFO] [1523284871.416538]: Capturing image failed.
[INFO] [1523284871.484537]: Capturing image failed.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2018-04-09**:
Please do not change your question that much after you got the first feedback. Your code doesn't even contain the loginfo anymore...

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-04-09**:
thank you so much, i add `cv2.waitKey(1)` camera is working..but how can i publish more camera images?
i mean i have 3 more cameras.
but when i remove log info, that works without error.